# This metal peg always hurts my collar bone, even though I do use a shoulder rest. What can I do?

Tags: violin

Is there any solution to this??
[image: metal peg on my violin]

Comment: How are you holding your violin?  Since the violin *should* have the shoulder rest place on your shoulder/collarbone region, I can't quite figure how the endpost could hit anything other than soft tissue in the neck.   Take a look at images from Google search, for example

Answer (score 10):

You have two solutions:

1. Don't press the violin into your body. Relax. This is what most of us do.
2. Do what we see Hilary Hahn doing in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcL0IsklM3M) and place a cloth over the offending parts of the violin.

Note that if you already have a hicky from previous pressure then the short term solution is number 2 until you have healed completely, but the long term solution is 1.

Comment: It always amuses me when you see a violinist with a beautiful violin worth thousands of pounds and *an ugly piece of kitchen sponge tied to it with baling twine*.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't able to adjust the height and position of your shoulder rest to find a comfortable place that lifts the end of your violin away from your collarbone, then you might look into replacing the chin rest ( what the metal piece is attached to) with a different model.

There are many different types and shapes of chin rest. Some mount on the left side of the tail piece, and can be small and low profile, or extend across the tailpiece and be higher and more centered. A left mounted chin rest would move the metal legs over and away from where they are now.

If it is the end button and not the chin rest legs that is bothering you, then an  option is to start adjusting your playing hold and position into a more comfortable location.